# Update and remove data from firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to modified or remove data in console Firestore and want to see the changes in my app. I use this code:

```
func checkForUpdates() {
    db.collection("sweets").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        //        whereField("name", isEqualTo: String.self).addSnapshotListener { order(by: "name")
        //whereField("timeStamp", isGreaterThan: Date()).addSnapshotListener {

        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach {
            diff in

            if (diff.type == .added) {
                self.sweetArray.append(Sweet(dictionary: diff.document.data())!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("document modified")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("document removed")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What me need to write in `if (diff.type == .modified)` and `if (diff.type == .removed)`?

If i modifi or remove data in console Firestore i see in console xCode `print("document modified")` or `print("document removed")`.

Comment: i guess - have a counter to check which position in array have the modified or removed data.